# Apply condition in BRE

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, business-rules, biztalk-rule-engine

Dear I want to match Rule values in BRE (One value coming from Database Table field(Rule) and the other is a .net property)

How I can do it?

I have tried a lot but couldn't succeeded. All the tutorials I have seen shows hard-coded values on one side.

Screenshot is given for reference:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks alot like what you are doing. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rgarg/archive/2009/04/23/using-biztalk-business-rules-engine-bre-with-database.aspx

Comment: Thanks for reply but I am calling BRE from .net application not from BizTalk. I can call it when there is no database involoved (just get and set property values or call a method etc) but when I want to match a value from database it doesn't execute. I am setting Fact Retriever class with database connection along with but no luck....